# how to call function key (F1, F2, F3) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, keyboard-shortcuts, uikeyboard

I'm trying to add a button in an IOS app using Swift so that when it's clicked, it executes F1...F12 in a regular keyboard for a Mac or Windows.
I look into UIKeyCommand but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean with calling a function key, are you trying to emulate some other software? Normally you want to call the action that corresponds to a certain key and not the key itself.

Comment: For example I got that website where it responds to any F1 or F2,,, calls whether Mac or Windows and I want it to respond to iPhone custom keyboard keys F1, F2,..  https://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html